# iOS insert View between Navigation Bar and View underneath it

Tags: ios

I want to insert an `UIView` between Navigation Bar and UIView (Underneath `NavigationBar`) to show network connectivity status.
Also View underneath Nav Bar should go downward to make a space for `indicatorView`.

My code:

```
indicatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, VIEW_WIDTH, 35)];
[self.view addSubview:indicatorView];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 35, VIEW_WIDTH, VIEW_HEIGHT - 35);
```

This inserts a view but whole window shift upwards and create a space at bottom of View. What's wrong?

Comment: you can show indicator in your status bar beside your carrier signal.

Comment: Yeah but I don't want that